# running remote check commands using icinga remote agent

Tags: icinga, system-monitoring, icinga2

I have icinga v2.11.3-1 installed on 4 servers, one as master and the rest are agent nodes and they are some-what properly configured because they are visible in icingaweb2 under hosts.

what I want to do is to be able to run a check command on a remote agent.

lets say I want to monitor disks on a server called `my-server`.

so in the master node I added the following configuration:

first defined the host and zone:

```
object Host "my-server" {
  import "generic-host"
        address = "my-server-host"
        vars.os = "Linux"
  vars.disks["disk /mnt/data"] = {
    disk_partitions =  "/mnt/data"
  }
  vars.agent_endpoint = name

}

object Endpoint "my-server" {
 host = "my-server"
}

object Zone "my-server" {
 endpoints = ["my-server"]
parent = "master"
}
```

notice that I added `vars.agent_endpoint`.

that applied the following on `disk` service:

```
apply Service "disk" {
  check_command = "disk"

  // Check is executed on the remote command endpoint
  command_endpoint = host.vars.agent_endpoint
  zone = host.vars.agent_endpoint
  assign where host.vars.agent_endpoint
}
```

and this is the the definition that checks for `host.vars.disks` that was already presented in the services.conf configuration file:

```
apply Service for (disk => config in host.vars.disks) {
  import "generic-service" 
  check_command = "disk"
  vars += config
}
```

yet it still checks for available space in the parent node and shows that result.

I probably missed something in the configuration and I don't know what

any ideas regarding this issue would be greatly appreciated.

thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so.. I couldn't find a way to resolve it manually.. but I found something even better!
I usually prefer configuring things manually but I found a plugin for icingaweb2 called director that made all the configuration for everything much much easier.

so the project is at https://github.com/Icinga/icingaweb2-module-director

so I removed icinga2 configuration and packages from all of my server and started clean, just installed icinga2 on all servers, ran `icinga2 node wizard` on all of them and configure icingaweb2 on the master node. here I still didn't see any of my servers because there wasn't any endpoints attached to them.

then I installed director, logged in to the director web interface, configured a host template with check command `hostalive` and `Icinaga2 Agent`, `Establish connection` and `Accepts config` set to yes.

then I created the hosts using this template.

then I created a service template for each monitoring item that I want to test and set `Run on agent to 'yes'.

then I created a service from that template service and attached it to the host template that I created so each service will be monitored on all of my agent based servers.

then I deployed the configuration and voila! works perfectly. detected the hosts, and executes the services monitoring tasks on those servers.

I was really impressed by this project, it was very easy to understand and to configure whatever I want.